# I am wondering about the relative between Step input and bandwidth

Tags: bandwidth

How we can do define the explanation of bandwidth in step input graph?

Sorry to not explain about problem deeply, cuz I am newbie about control theory.

in book , that explaining smaller 3dB of when frequency =0

but i cant understand where is frequncy on the step input graph.

[image]

Comment: The step response graph is a time domain graph. We cannot directly see bandwidth or frequency in it. However, the approximate value of band width can be calculated from the rise time seen in the step response.

Comment: "*in book , that explaining smaller 3dB of when frequency =0*". This statement is unclear. Please add the content of the book where this is mentioned.

Comment: @AJN p.574 of the  Modern control systems book 13th edition(Richard C.Dorf ) there said The bandwidth is the frequency ωB at which the frequency response has declined 3 dB from its low-frequency value.
This corresponds to approximately half an octave, or about 1 / √2 of the low-frequency value.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. We just call it the 3 dB bandwidth or the 3 dB cut-off for a low pass filter as per your picture. 3 dB cut-off can usually be found by extracting information from the picture shown but it's a bit tortuous to get an answer with sufficient accuracy.

Comment: Thank you everyone!! I got well just now, thank you.